# Broken OS X terminal prompt after installing GRASS via homebrew

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm using GRASS on OS X. After installing GRASS I can no longer open my terminal to a prompt.

On opening the terminal, the following line runs by itself

```
/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
```

And GRASS starts but itself. I can't find how to stop terminal from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if terminal is similar to its shell as linux but do you have a .bashrc or something similar that the shell looks at to load your terminal session? .profile in /home/{username}? Inside one of the 'hidden' folders in your home directory could be where

```
/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
```

is hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what has happened is the GRASS brew did something stupid and added that line to the end of either your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or possibly `~/.profile` file (`~` is your home directory - something like `/Users/Willburt`). Unfortunately I'm not at my Mac now to test this, but try opening Terminal.app, going to the Preferences, and in the Startup tab select "Shells Open With: Command (Complete Path)" and type in `env - "$(command -v bash)" --noprofile --norc`. This will start up `bash` (the standard login shell on OSX) but not execute any of the files I mentioned above.

Once you're in, use `/bin/ls -la` to list all the files in your home directory, including the "hidden" ones (those that start with a `.`) and see which of the above files you have. Use `cat filename` to list the contents of the files, and `/bin/vi filename` to edit the file(s) to remove the offending line. If you haven't used `vi` before, here are the key commands: You'll start in "command mode", which means you can move around, but can't type anything. Hit <kbd>i</kbd> (lowercase letter I) to enter "insert mode", move to where you want with the arrow keys, then put a `#` symbol as the very first character on the offending line so it doesn't get executed the next time. When you're done editing, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `:wq` to write the file to disk and quit. Keep in mind that the line may not be

```
/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh'; exit
```

exactly, it may be something like `/usr/local/bin/rungrass` or something similar.

After all this tomfoolery, close your `bash` session, go back into the Preferences and change them back to what they were before, and *hopefully* you should be all set.

---

As a completely different way to fix this, move `/Applications/GRASS-6.4.app` to some other location, like your Desktop, then you can use Terminal.app like normal to find and edit your startup files. Your choice :)